# Any legacy-like boot themes for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, themes, customization

Is there any way to get Ubuntu boot to look like Knoppix boot? Or anything in legacy-style?

[knoppix-boot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsCfh.png)

Comment: Not a theme, just console. Pretty much any distro can boot in text mode by removing `quiet splash` Grub (or equivalent) parameters.

Comment: Yea, I know that. What I ask is if there is any way to customize that boot text? Like changing font, size, color? Adding images?